# Is $\gamma$ homotopic to $g\circ\gamma$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a simply connected topological space. Let $x_0,x_1\in X$ and let $\gamma$ be a path in $X$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$. Let $g$ be a homeomorphism of $X$ with itself. Then $g\circ\gamma$ is a path in $X$ from $g(x_0)$ to $g(x_1)$.

> **Is $\gamma$ homotopic to $g\circ\gamma$?** (NOT path homotopic, just homotopic)

I think it should be true but I can't seem to give a homotopy from $\gamma$ to $g\circ\gamma$. That is I need a continuous map $F:I\times I\rightarrow X$ such that $F(s,0)=\gamma(s)$ and $F(s,1)=g\circ\gamma(s)$ for all $s\in I$.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that since you only ask for homotopy, and not path homotopy, every map $I\to X$ is homotopic to a constant map. So it suffices when $X$ is path-connected since then the two constant paths are homotopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is simply connected, every two paths are homotopic (almost) by definition.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought at first. But don't we say any two paths with the same starting point and ending point are path homotopic and not just that any two paths are homotopic?

Comment: I suppose that a simply connected space is also connected. In that case you can join the two starting and ending points with a continuous curve. Hence you assign the value of the homotopy $F$ on the boundary of $I\times I$. The function can then be extended on the interior by the definition of *simply connectedness*. If, instead, a simply connected space is not required to be connected, the statement is obviously false.

Comment: I see. You are right. A simply connected space is by definition path connected so what you have said will work. Thank you!